# Lint task never finishes for Android multi-module project with dynamic feature module

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-lint, dynamic-feature-module

Our app contains over 20 multi-modules and one on-demand dynamic feature module.

Before adding dynamic feature module, it took 20-30 mins for lint task to complete both on CI and local, but after adding dynamic feature module, it DOES NOT COMPLETE even after 1-2 hours both in CI and local, and it is now becoming a serious problem.

I assume that taking 20-30mins for lint is already a weird situation, but we do like to first solve the problem of lint not finishing its task at all.

I have looked over [the issue tracker about supporting dynamic feature module](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113198298#comment5); although it says that the issue has been solved and says that `checkDependencies` flag is unnecessary, removing the flag does not change the situation in our project.

On CI, we run gradle command `./gradlew app:lint{Flavor}Debug` (In our case, `./gradlew app:lintDevDebug` )to run the lint.

Here is our gradle config for `app`:

```
app/build.gradle

lintOptions {
    // several disable config
    disable ...
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    checkDependencies true // making it 'false' does not seem to solve the issue
    abortOnError false
    textReport true
    textOutput 'stdout'
  }
```

There is no lint config for any other build.gradle files on other modules or the dynamic feautre module.

Any help or comment would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: have you found a workaroud for this particular problems?

Comment: @mochadwi My colleague found out that removing 
`dynamicFeatures = ["your-dfm-module-name"]` config from app/build.gradle temporarily fixes this issue.. When running CI, we dynamically remove this config.

Comment: i see, but then the dynamicFeatures not scanned by linters?

Comment: You're right. The DFM won't be scanned by linters.